# Replicating cells with addition of sequential number based on a variable

Tags: excel, numbers, sequential, vba

looking for some help in excel with a replication process. Would prefer to do by formula but I am pretty sure it will need to be VBA. On sheet 1 I have two columns; A has distinct names, B has a number ranging from 1 to 15. I need to create a column on sheet 2 with the name in sheet 1 column A replicated the number of time specified on sheet 1 column B. In addition, I need to add the replication count to the value being created on sheet 2.

As an example
Sheet 1

```
column A, column B
sam, 3
susan, 2
```

sheet 2 column a would look like

```
sam1
sam2
sam3
susan1
susan2
```

Been rummaging around the net for some time and just can’t find the right combination of code. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should do what you want:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim row1 As Long
Dim row2 As Long
Dim iter As Long
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
row1 = 1
row2 = 1
Do While ws1.Cells(row1, 1).Value <> ""
    For iter = 1 to ws1.Cells(row1, 2).Value
        ws2.Cells(row2, 1).Value = ws1.Cells(row1, 1).Value & iter
        row2 = row2 + 1
    Next
    row1 = row1 + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you - does exactly as needed so I kinda feel like an idiot asking this question. I was still digging for a formula solution and came across this.
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,IF(MOD(ROW(A12),12)=0,"",ROUNDUP(ROW(A12)/12,0)),1),"")
Basically, fill down with this and it parses in a similar manner. 
This works except the count is fixed at a set value in the formula. I do not believe it is possible but can it be modified to read a specified value like the VBA?
Again, thank you for the VBA and will use it unless I can find a formula.
Scott

Comment: I can think of a way that I **might** be able to do it just using Excel formulae, but it would take several columns, and wouldn't be pretty.  I wouldn't use such a method myself unless this was the **only** part of the process that was requiring VBA.

Comment: I agree and that is my rub. Document is numerous tabs deep with various vlookups replicating data for various groups. This set is the only one requiring a script. Concern is someone will update one of the other primary tables and not run the script to complete updates to this tab. What you provided works great and I appreciate the help. Would really like to remove the one manual update step if possible.